# Shell Script To Monitor Completion of RAID Assembly

Tags: raid, bash, mdadm

How can I pause execution of my shell script after calling the following command until the raid array has been assembled?  From what I understand, this is an asynchronous process and status of the raid array needs to be polled.

mdadm --create -l10 -n4 /dev/md0 /dev/xvdh*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're creating a new RAID 10, you can begin using the array immediately. The initial resync will continue in the background. You only need to wait for it to complete if building a RAID 5 array (and it's a good idea for a RAID 6, too).

See [Initial Array Creation](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Initial_Array_Creation) in the Linux RAID Wiki for further details.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit Sat Oct 27 17:03:42 CDT 2012:**

While it's true that you can work with the RAID 10 array before it's finished re syncing, I figured that I would answer the question about how to pause during the re-sync process anyway.

**This is how you pause the script for the re-syncing process (IMO/AFAIK/etc.):**

```
# Add this where you want to pause...
while [ -n "$(mdadm --detail /dev/md0 | grep -ioE 'State :.*resyncing')" ]; do
    sleep 1
done
```

To use the example above, the whole script would be:

```
mdadm --create -l10 -n4 /dev/md0 /dev/xvdh*

while [ -n "$(mdadm --detail /dev/md0 | grep -ioE 'State :.*resyncing')" ]; do
    sleep 1
done

mke2fs -t ext4 -F /dev/md0
```

Please note that the above script is not tested and may contain bugs.

Comment: thanks.  that works for the mke2fs command.  but the raid array being built is an asynchronous process.  the command "mdadm --detail /dev/md0" is used to query the status.

Comment: i updated my question to clarify what I'm asking.

Comment: @VinnyD Oh, then this becomes a bit more complex.  Please post an example of what `mdadm --detail /dev/md0` says while you want it paused.

Comment: thanks for your help :) the response below answers my question.

Comment: @VinnyD  See latest edit...